# app.bundle.js:sourcemap:28063 Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux, and I am trying to integrate a basic version just to get a solid platform to build from. I was basing this off of the basic setup at : [Super Simple React-Redux Setup](http://blog.tylerbuchea.com/super-simple-react-redux-application-example/)

I do have it split into three files, but for some reason it is return the error mentioned above in the createStore function.

#### actions.js

```
export const increment= state => ({
  type: "INCREMENT",
  state
})
```

#### reducer.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import increment from './actions';

export const myFunctions= (state= {}, action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case "INCREMENT":
      state.value += 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
   return state;
 }

 export const reducers = combineReducers({
   myFunctions
 });
```

#### store.js

```
import { createStore, compose} from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducer.js';

export function configureStore(initialState = {value: 1}) {
  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState);
  return store;
};

export const store = configureStore();
```

I am just a little curious as to why this is hapening, is there something absurdly obvious that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer file does not have a default export which means that when you import the file in your store it will be undefined.

Update your reducer.js to the following

reducer.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import increment from './actions';

const myFunctions= (state= {}, action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case "INCREMENT":
      state.value += 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
   return state;
 }

 const reducers = combineReducers({
   myFunctions
 });

 export default reducers;
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I thought that by having export before const would automatically export the function.

Comment: It does but the syntax to access the function is different. A non-default export statement is called a named export an can be accessed in your case with `import { reducers } from './reducers'` since the name of your exported variable is `reducers`